# i can't upload a file named in Arabic letters - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, forms, file, file-upload

i am trying to upload a file while register in laravel 8

when the uploaded file is named in English it will continue the register but if the uploaded file named in Arabic letters the form won't accept that, what is the solution for this problem?

```
    $request = request();
    $profileImage = $request->file('uploadfile');
    $profileImageSaveAsName = time() . "aa" . "-profile." . $profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

view:

```
<div style="font-family: Frutiger;" class="mt-4 text-right">
                    <x-jet-label for="uploadfile" value="{{ __(' * ملف المشاركة     ') }}" />
                    <x-jet-input id="uploadfile" class="block mt-1 w-full text-right border" type="file" name="uploadfile" value="dsfs" required autofocus autocomplete="uploadfile" />
                   
                </div>
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: i'm not getting any error, just getting redirect to registration page

Comment: can you mention file name so ican reproduce the same

Comment: i have updated the question with the view code

Comment: can you mention file name of uplaoded .so  ican try to upload same name in lcoal

Comment: "ملف المشاركة" you can try this

Comment: i have tested in local and it works fine .you can dd($profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension()) to verify extension .sicne you are generating random name

Comment: so i just update my code to be like this: "dd($profileImage->getClientOriginalExtension());" ?

Comment: its for testing whether you get extension of file or not.

Comment: How about your file extension and also your validation in your file?

Comment: the input accept any file actually and when i upload a file in English letters (which is the same file in Arabic letters) it won't accept it, i did the testing and i got ".png"